# Book about a boy and a dragon who meet at the beach that's written by an Irish or Scottish author?

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I read this book about 6 or 7 years ago and I can’t remember the title

This boy found a big dragon shaped rich at the beach and it turns out it was a real dragon. They become friends and fly together. The dragon even gives him a boy to stay in contact.

When the boy goes to camp the dragon meets him at a lake and they have load of adventures.

It may be a series?

Comment: "dragon shaped rich"...? Did you mean a dragon-shaped rock?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?  Was this a paperback, hardcover or e-book?

Comment: @Moana Melanie McCort  You say that the dragon gives the boy a boy.  Do you mean that the boy protagonist becomes a slave owner?

Comment: @M.A.Golding perhaps a *way* to stay in contact?

Comment: Might be the same story as https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22673592-children-ya-fantasy-book-about-a-boy-and-a-dragon-based-in-the-real-wo, where he gives him a scale.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It might also be the same Moana.

Comment: Indeed. :-D Not quite confident enough to just edit those bits in.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2064845 has a girl meeting and befriending a dragon on the beach. There are four books in the series, but none seem to mention camp.

Comment: Wait, "The dragon gives him a boy to stay in contact"? The dragon just has a boy and gives that boy to the other boy? I'm confused.